# Space text in row but only based on one child widget

Tags: flutter

So I want to create this:

```
|     12          5          300     |
|   monkeys    baboons   chimpanzees |
```

Basically, put the widgets in a `Row` and use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround` on the numbers. The problem is, the text is disrupting the spacing, and since 'chimpanzees' is longer, it causes the `5 baboons` to be off center. What is the best way to have the `spaceAround` only align the numbers, then center the text underneath the numbers?

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    children: <Widget>[
        Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                Text('12'),
                Text('monkeys'),
            ],
        ),
        Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                Text('5'),
                Text('baboons'),
            ],
        ),
        Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                Text('300'),
                Text('chimpanzees'),
            ],
        ),
    ],
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `Expanded()` to have same width for the `Row()` children. No need to use `spaceAround`.

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                    Text('12'),
                    Text('monkeys'),
                ],
            ),
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                    Text('5'),
                    Text('baboons'),
                ],
            ),
        ),
        Expanded(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                    Text('300'),
                    Text('chimpanzees'),
                ],
            ),
        ),
    ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,